# Android M, loading a MapFragement without ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: android, permissions, location, mapfragment, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am working on an Android M project where the user gets prompted for Location permission to view a map, in case of denial I would like to show just a U.S continental view (without the user's location), for some reason I am not able to achieve that. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The flow for checking/requesting permission is totally separate from showing the my location layer on a map or controlling the camera - what part are you having problems with?

Comment: My issue here is with loading a map without having the location permission, I will posting relevant code to that.

Comment: `MapFragment` and `MapView` don't require the location permission. I'd suggest opening other questions if you have issues with the Android M permission flow or moving the camera to capture a generic map region.